# Reputation from upvote after reaching cap

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I saw this in my Reputation page:

[image]

As you can see I got an upvote at `17:16` after reaching the cap. And then again at `20:04` I got an upvote, but this time I got the reputation.

Can you tell me how is that possible?

Comment: How does this agree with http://stackoverflow.com/reputation ?

Comment: @Oded: I can't believe that still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that somewhere between 13:51 and 17:16 you got upvote on one of your posts, which was the 20th upvote for that day i.e. rep cap, hence the upvote on 17:16 did not give you reputation.

Now, somewhere between 17:16 and 20:04 that post was deleted or the upvote was undone, so there was a place for yet one more upvote to take effect.

Try checking "show deleted posts" in your reputation tab and maybe you'll see something.

Comment: tnx for the response. checking "show deleted posts"  didn't revealed secret information though i could use to see them... but if someone unvoted me then why didn't i get reputation on the 17:16 answer? is the reputation doesn't get recalculated?

Comment: @LiranElisha I don't think that it's recalculated upon unupvote. However I fear we can't really detect unupvote events that are not recorded.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday you got 20 upvotes and 7 accepts, so it is 200+105=305. Hence, I guess:

- at 17.15 you had 20 upvotes.
- at 17.16 you got an upvote and did not count towards reputation.
- before 20.04 some of your previous answers with upvotes from yesterday was moved / an upvote was retracted so that you went back to 19 upvotes by then.
- an upvote was done at 20.04 so you finished with 20 upvotes.